# Add custom cell to UITableview without editing

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have been struggling with this thing for a while so I finally decided to ask to see what I'm doing wrong.

I created a custom UITableViewCell that has a UITextField as a subView in the cells Content View. What I'm trying to accomplish is to insert a new row below it with the standard placeholder when the textView begins editing. I assumed this would be possible in the method below but I always get a crash. Is there a way to do this?

I'm new to iOS and tableviews still get me everytime.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)self.view;

        if ([textField tag] == 2) { // Only add row if textfield 2 is editing

            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        }
    [textField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
    [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
```

If someone has some pointers or some reference (Aside from apple's documentation) it will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem occuring in only this application or all applications.  What I mean chek once enter values in UITextfeild. Check is it going crash or not

Comment: I'm not shure I understand this. When I press the cell the textview begins editing and the method that i posted gets called. I'm pretty sure is my own fault because I'm indexing wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is the problem occuring in Simulator or Device. Check once.

Comment: In the device. My deployment target is iOS version 4.0

Comment: Use try and catch and the exception info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the collection which is the source for the `tableView` before insertion.

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

What this does is it immediately queries the data source and delegate. Now you may want to insert the "place holder", but does your array or dictionary hold whatever is required to return the data correctly? If you are going to insert a new row and the source is not updated correctly, it will crash. So to rectify it, you need to modify the source before you begin the updates for the `tableView`.

I know you don't want apple's doc, but have a look at this and it might solve your problem.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9

Comment: This doc was where I got the idea from. But the thing is, I still don't know if i can call this from the textfield didbegin method.

Comment: @AndresBucci I'm sorry but call what? what is your tableview's source?

Comment: I want to insert a custom UITableCell with its default parameters, so if I understood you i have to make an array with this new cell and then insert the row?